# Airflow - create task that runs once all other tasks ran successfully

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Is there a way to add a task that runs once all other tasks have run successfully in the same DAG, see below for my current DAG.

For example my current tasks run in the below order, but I want to add `new_task` once all of the below runs. If I leave it as the below it won't run `new_task`:

```
for endpoint in ENDPOINTS:
      latest_only = (operator...)
      s3 = (operator...)
      etc ....


      latest_only >> s3 >> short_circuit
      short_circuit >> snowflake >> success
      short_circuit >> postgres >> success
      if endpoint.name == "io_lineitems":
        success >> il_io_lineitems_tables
copy_monthly_billing >> load_io_monthly_billing_to_snowflake
copy_monthly_billing >> load_io_monthly_billing_to_postgres
new_task
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use trigger rules to trigger based on upstream task success status
[trigger_rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/concepts.html?highlight=trigger%20rule#trigger-rules)